# Как сделать запрос vue axios в laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Создал новый проект Laravel, на странице подключил Vue.js через cdn
Есть контроллер, маршрут. Как сделать запрос ?

```
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
      <button  @click="toggle" class="btn btn-primary m-3">Загрузить</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data:{
        posts: null,
      },
      methods:{
        toggle() {
        axios
        .get('api/v1/users')
        .then(response => this.posts = response.data)
        .catch(error => this.posts = [{title: 'Посты не найдены.'}])
        .finally(() => console.log('Посты успешно загружены'));
        },
      }
    });
  </script>
```

В ответ получаю ошибку 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Ну ошибка о чем говорит? Запрос отправляешь правильно. Мы ж не знаем как авторизация на ручке происходит. Не пущает, потому что не авторизован.

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста как исправить ошибку ?

Comment: Авторизоваться там, куда стучишься?

Comment: В контроллер     public function index()
    {

        return "OK";
    }

Comment: `php artisan route:list | grep users` в студию

Comment: | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | api/v1/users                             | api.users.index                  | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Admin\UsersApiController@index

Comment: Ну вот, у вас `auth` - авторизация стоит. Это мидлвар. Он либо в `routes/api.php` либо в `__construct()` контроллера сидит. Для API по идее нужно [использовать токены](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication)

Comment: Посмотрите эту доку https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport